# Rails: Rolify can not generate user model because one has existed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Rails 5.0
Ruby 2.3
Rolify 5.1

I am following rolify's tutorial to do `rails g rolify Role User`. 
But a user model have already existed in my project and it is just an normal user model.
 The model to manage users' log in and log out is a model called log_user.
So for now two models have existed `user and login_user`. 
So rails can not generate another user for me. I am not familiar with rolify. Anyone could tell me what I can do to solve this problem?

when I tried `rails g rolify Role User`, error

> /Users/King/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/‌​thor/actions/inject_‌​into_file.rb:95:in binread': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /Users/...../app/models/user.rb (Errno::ENOENT)

==========================UPDATE=================================
when I tried `rails g rolify:role Role User`, error shows

```
kingk-Pro:mypj King$ rails g rolify:role Role User
Running via Spring preloader in process 97622
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--test-framework'; got false (boolean)
Could not find generator 'rolify:role'. Maybe you meant 'rolify:user', 'rolify' or 'controller'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .....

First, create your Role model and migration file using this generator:

`rails g rolify Role User`

For versions of Rolify prior to 3.3, use:

`rails g rolify:role Role User`

rolify just adds some class methods in an existing User class.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: `/Users/Bigbrother/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:95:in binread': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/...../app/models/user.rb (Errno::ENOENT)` still have the same error

Comment: Shows a different error, please see my updated description

Comment: `rails g rolify:user Role User` try this.

Comment: There is an open issue on Github https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/409 , I think the issue is with Rails 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130125/discussion-between-akshay-and-marco-song).

Comment: I forgot to say, my project have two parts , one is called base , another called mypj. base contains all models and migration, mypj contains all of other parts of project and called base in gemfile. I tried the command you said in both parts, but no one works. For the purpose of test, I create a new rails project, the command works. I am not sure whether problem happened because there are two parts of my project